# MVC4 WebAPI + JSON Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, post, forms-authentication

I have created a new MVC4 Web Project and its all working correctly with user login etc.

I've added a WebAPI onto this which will return data from Entity Framework.

I want to be able to login from a mobile app, be able to call and API and return results based on the user that is logged in.

I sent a POST request to Account/Login with content type as application/json; charset=utf-8, however I keep getting the following error message:

>

> The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException: The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

How would I solve this? or generate the anti-forgery cookie?

I've had a look on the net, but these involved an asp.net based solution - i will be making these requests from iOS / Android..

Thanks.

Comment: if I comment out [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] in the AccountController.cs it seems to work ok? is it secure to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you've actually solved the problem; the WCF Authentication service has nothing to do with anti-forgery tokens.  Anti-forgery tokens are a technique used to stop something called **Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)**. There's a good explanation of it over on [Steve Sanderson's blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/).  The implementation basics are that you have a tag in the view (see the snippet) and then the attribute `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` over the actions that you want MVC to "enforce" the token's presence on:

```
<% using(Html.Form("UserProfile", "SubmitUpdate")) { %>
    <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
    <!-- rest of form goes here -->
<% } %>
```

The reason why you're seeing that exception is that you're POSTing to Account/Login without including the anti-forgery token.  If you're trying to handle login/authentication through a Web API method, you can still use anti-forgery tokens.  Just make sure to [pass it to your view](http://feetens.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/anti-forgery-with-web-api-in-asp-net-mvc-4-rc/) to POST back to the API.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I used the WCF Authentication Service instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398990(VS.100).aspx